# C# store numbers like 10^-38 in an variable

Tags: c#, variables, numbers, precision

Dezimal and float cant store a number as small as 10^-38.
Any suggestions on how I can save this number in a var.

Comment: No idea what you are asking for. Did you do any research on the various types that the C# languages offers to you? As in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables

Comment: Just check the type of this variable: `var x = 1e-38;`

Comment: The range of double ends at 5*10-324. And the range of float is defined as: "-3.4 × 10^38" so still abrely within your area. So we are confused what you are even asking about.

Comment: Are you looking for *floating point* type (`double` in your case), not *binary decimal* `decimal`? E.g. `double test = 1e-38;`

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft's types and variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables) you should be able to store that value in a double : 64 bits, range from 5.0 × 10^-324 to 1.7 × 10^308, with 15-digit precision

Answer (score 1):

While there's no formal BigDecimal class in the .NET Framework, there are many implementations out there that have an underlying reference to BigInteger.

You won't get anywhere near the performance that you would with the simple data types like Decimal, Double or Float, but they should work.

A couple examples:
    https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136
    https://github.com/Limeoats/BigDecimal

Comment: Microsoft has their own implementation as well, called [BigRational](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/bcl/blob/master/Wiki/BigRational.md).